# Нужная иконка в трее

Tags: windows, winapi, c++

Привет всем, хотел спросить, как сделать на панели трей (вроде так она называется, где часы, антивирус и все такое) нужный значок, то бишь чтобы при старте Windows просто загружался нужный значек.

Answer (score 1):

1. Создать приложение, которое будет запускаться вместе с Windows. Выбрать такой [класс окна](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632596(v=VS.85).aspx) для приложения, что самого окна не будет ни в панели задач, ни на экране.
2. Прописать ключ реестра "`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`" при установке приложения, чтобы обеспечить автозапуск.
3. В самом приложении после запуска установить в трей требуемую иконку с помощью [Shell_NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762159(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Вот те готовая функция:

```
BOOL TrayMessage(HWND hDlg, DWORD dwMessage, UINT uID, HICON hIcon, PSTR pszTip)
{
        BOOL res;

    NOTIFYICONDATA tnd;

    tnd.cbSize      = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
    tnd.hWnd        = hDlg;
    tnd.uID         = uID;

    tnd.uFlags      = NIF_MESSAGE|NIF_ICON|NIF_TIP;
    tnd.uCallbackMessage    = MYWM_NOTIFYICON;
    tnd.hIcon       = hIcon;
    if (pszTip)
    {
        lstrcpyn(tnd.szTip, pszTip, sizeof(tnd.szTip));
    }
    else
    {
        tnd.szTip[0] = '\0';
    }

    res = Shell_NotifyIcon(dwMessage, &tnd);

    if (hIcon)
        DestroyIcon(hIcon);

    return res;
}
```

Вот, например, как высветить иконку при сворачивании окна при помощи этой функции (в MFC, в чистом API еще проще, просто скопировал из своего кода, что было):

```
void CMyServerDlg::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy) 
{

HICON hIcon;

    if(nType==SIZE_MINIMIZED)
    {

    hIcon=AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
    TrayMessage(m_hWnd,NIM_ADD,0,hIcon,
        "Такая-то программа - открыть окно");//будет высвечиваться подсказка если навести мышку на иконку
    ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);

    }
    else
    {
        TrayMessage(m_hWnd,NIM_DELETE,0,NULL,NULL);
    }
    CDialog::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);
}
```

Если надо при старте можно сделать программу вообще без окна (чистый WinMain с обработкой WM_TIMER в цикле) или же с окном, которое инициально показывается с флагом SW_HIDE